# Are there any minecraft mods that allow players to have a different inventory per dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-mods, minecraft-forge

In the past, I know that there used to be plugins that allowed you to separate inventories between dimensions, in this case if a server had custom dimensions.

I am wondering if there's a **forge mod** that does the same thing, for some of the newest versions like 1.18 or 1.19.

I have done a couple term searches on Google, but it looks like it's a forgotten concept, or I'm just terrible at term searching.

Unfortunately, I am not sure if general server plugins work on Forge, and as such, I'd rather only deal with forge mods. I am trying to make a mini-game on a modpack server, however the modpack it runs on (ATM8) means that players would have items that'd lead to an unfair advantage in the mini-game, unless their inventory is temporarily set to nothing.

I could ask players to store all of their stuff in ender chests until the mini-game is over, but you can probably tell this is not an ideal solution, and would rather have this be an automated process.

Comment: What I think most popular servers do is run 2 servers at once and use something like bungeecord. Not sure if it works with forge mods though, and it could be quite recource intensive. The latest versions of minecraft have the /item command which you can use to make a datapack that switches players' inventories with chests kept safe in forceloaded chunks outside the worldborder or in a custom dimension that you can't visit.

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but this is probably possible to implement with command blocks using a technique similar to [How would you copy a player's inventory into a double chest?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/374406/185203)